# Comparing runtimes between solutions

Tags: python

I have two solutions in Python for the following Leetcode problem:

[image]

The first solution took 704 ms:

```
d = dict()

for index, num in enumerate(nums):
    if num in d.keys():
        return d[num], index
    else:
        d[target - num] = index
```

The second solution took only 36 ms:

```
d = dict()

for i in range(len(nums)):
    if (target - nums[i]) in d:
        return d[target-nums[i]], i
    else:
        d[nums[i]] = i
```

I'm not sure why the 2nd solution is much faster than the first solution. The approach is very similar but the only difference I can see is that the first solution uses enumerate() whereas the second solution uses range(). Any ideas behind this?

Comment: The other differences are that 3 of the remaining 4 lines do something different.

Comment: What was the input you used to determine the runtimes? How did you measure the runtimes?

Comment: I'm not sure what input they used as it's a leetcode problem. https://leetcode.com/problems/two-sum/

Comment: @Olympus [Check](https://repl.it/repls/MajesticBleakDesignmethod) this out. I benchmarked both the solutions for you. The 1st solution was faster than the second one.

Comment: Thanks! I made a mistake when copying the second solution. It should be 'xxx in d' and not 'xxx in d.keys()'. The 2nd solution should be faster now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The performance of these two solutions will be impacted by the order of items in the list (i.e. the nature of your test data). Also, using `xxx in d.keys()` performs a sequential search whereas `xxx in d will` give the same result but much faster and will be less impacted by item order